# How do I get a difference between two dates in days?

Tags: r, date

I need to get a difference between two dates(timestamps) in days such as `(2021-03-08 00:01:01) - (2021-03-07 23:59:59)` will be equal to 1. I tried to use day() function, but there is a problem: if two dates have different month, it returns wrong result, such as `(2021-03-01 12:12:12) - (2021-02-27 12:12:12)` will be equal to -26, but I need 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how your dates are formatted, but try `as.Date`

```
-diff(as.Date(c("2021-03-08 00:01:01", "2021-03-07 23:59:59")))
# Time difference of 1 days

-diff(as.Date(c("2021-03-01 12:12:12", "2021-02-27 12:12:12")))
# Time difference of 2 days
```

If you just want the numbers wrap a `as.numeric(...)` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
max(df$date) - min(df$date)
```

This subtracts the minimum (earliest) date in the `date` field from the maximum (latest) date in the `date` field to produce an output of:

```
> max(df$date) - min(df$date)
Time difference of 28 days
```

Just make sure that the field `df$date` is in date format:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```